# check spelling using php but output empty screen apear?

Tags: php

Spelling check using php, but output shows nothing, empty screen appears... How to fix it? Please help me.

```
    <?php
    function spellSuggest($string)
    {
    $config_dic = pspell_config_create('en');
    pspell_config_ignore($config_dic, 3);
    pspell_config_mode($config_dic, PSPELL_FAST);
    $dictionary = pspell_new_config($config_dic);
    $replacement_suggest = false;
    $string = explode(' ', trim(str_replace(',', ' ', $string)));
    foreach ($string as $key => $value) {
        if(!pspell_check($dictionary, $value)) {
            $suggestion = pspell_suggest($dictionary, $value); 
           if(isset($suggestion [0]) && (strtolower($suggestion [0]) != strtolower($value))) {
                $string [$key] = $suggestion [0];
                $replacement_suggest = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($replacement_suggest) {
    return implode(' ', $string);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    }
    echo spellSuggest("This is amazingly asewome");
    ?>
```

Comment: do you have library of this `pspell_config_create()`?

Comment: looks like `$replacement_suggest` is `false`, right?

Comment: sorry cannot understand @ Mr. Anant

Comment: please replacement my code

Comment: Please be sure to use `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: i replacement $replacement_suggest true, but cannot suggest show "This is amazingly asewome", what can do

Comment: how to fix@Mr.jeff

Comment: Are you sure you have the [pspell extension](http://php.net/manual/en/pspell.installation.php) installed? A blank screen generally means you're getting an error but not viewing it, so in that case some good [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/4233593) would probably help.

Comment: If `$replacement_suggest` is `false` then you are returning `null` So nothing will be shown. Now why your dictionary does not have any suggestion, you have to debug your code to see if it's throwing any exception in your function or not.